# Backup Oracle DB using TSM server version 6.3.0

Tags: oracle, linux, ibm-tsm

I'm new to Oracle and TSM server. I installed Oracle11gR2 and TSM server version 6.3.0 (linux Centos 6.4 OS). 
I did the configuration and everything works fine. so far I arrive to run the following script using rman:

```
run {
allocate channel Channel1 type 'SBT_TAPE' parms
'ENV=(DSMO_NODE=TDPOTSMUSR,DSMO_AVG_SIZE=1,TDPO_OPTFILE=/opt/tivoli/tsm/client/oracle/bin64/
tdpo.opt,DSMI_LOG=/opt/tivoli/tsm/client/api/bin64/logs)';
backup
        full
        format 'b_%u_%p_%c'
        database;
release channel Channel1 ;
}
```

I need to know how to backup theOracle DB to a storagepool name ORADisk? I need to understand a bit what does channel mean in a script and what does it actually do.
really appreciate your hel and reply. thank you

Answer (score 1):

to backup the Oracle DB to a storagepool name ORADisk this is done through backup policy by tsm server not the client by assign the client to a domain then assign it to the group policy.

channel is oracle rman command used to hold the new settings for this backup session only without any changes to the rman predefined settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. If you may one more question, My OS Linux Centos 6.4 is running on a vmware, I downloaded an Virtual tape library VTL (https://sites.google.com/site/linuxvtl2/home#mhvtl-download), After I download it, I tried to define the drive name /dev/st1 in the TSM Server, but I keep having this error: ANR8420E DEFINE PATH: An I/O error occurred while accessing drive ST1.

Any help please would be appreciated.
thank you :D

Comment: this is a new question that should be opened in an appropriate stack exchange.